# How to modify my query for the below requirement?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query where I can the `order_seq_num` as 2 but I want to get value from the column `test_group_id` from the `t_patient_mhc_step_group_mapping` for `selected order_seq_num` if the order_seq_num selected the row value 2 in `t_patient_mhc_step_mapping`.

```
SELECT 
    IF((labrep.lab_status_id = 2
            && labrep.mhc_status = 'MHC'),
        MIN(stepmap.order_seq_num) + 1,
        MIN(stepmap.order_seq_num)) AS step_order_seq_num
FROM
    `t_patient_mhc_step_group_mapping` stepgroup
        INNER JOIN
    t_patient_mhc_step_mapping stepmap ON stepgroup.step_id = stepmap.step_id
        AND stepmap.mhc_step_status = 1
        INNER JOIN
    `t_patient_mhc_mapping` mhcmap
        INNER JOIN
    `t_lab_test_report` labrep ON labrep.op_ip_appt_id = mhcmap.appt_id
WHERE
    mhcmap.appt_id = 81
```

Comment: Would you show some example input and output data of what you want, and show how your current query doesn't quite work? If you can create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for your current query that will give readers something to play with too.

Comment: We'd need to see your table schemas as well, so please add in a `SHOW CREATE TABLE x` for the tables involved.